# Apache is Adding Javascript in HTML File

Tags: apache, http, security

I got a strange situation where my Apache Server is adding a piece of Javascript code just before closing tag of the served HTML content.

I tried to find out but could not success what is going here on the server. I restarted the server and then it went away, but after sometime I'm facing same issue.

I'm sure my server is compromized and someone is doing this act. Kindly help me where to look to check how Apache can add such code on the fly on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have set up anything like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page), it's likely that your server got compromised.

As a first step, I suggest you check, if anything like this has been configured.

Beware though, if your server has been compromised, it's very likely that the attacker still maintains access to your server. If you can, nuke it, rotate credentials and look into hardening your servers.

Comment: No I did not configure anything. But I tried to check all the cache and other substitute modules but they are not configured et all, still I have no clue how attacker is changing the response. I tried to access the file using wget but still same code is getting inserted, I was doubting some Javascript code is working behind the scene but if wget is also giving same result then there is no role of Javascript.

Comment: did you check the settings in the question i've linked? i suspect a cryptojacker gets injected - but that's only speculation.

Comment: Yes I checked it but I could not find any script which is pointed by Apache.

Comment: Then I'd assume your server got compromised.